# Why does the Couchbase Server API require a name for new documents

Tags: couchbase

When you create a document using the Couchbase Server API, one of the arguments is a document name. What is this used for and why is it needed?

When using Couchbase Lite you can create an empty document and it is assigned an _id and _rev. You do not need to give it a name. So what is this argument for in Couchbase Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Couchbase Server it is a design decision that all objects are identified by a the object ID, key or name (all the same thing by different names) and those are not auto-assigned. The reason for this is that keys are not embedded in the document itself, key lookups are the fastest way to get that object and the technology dictates this under the hood of the server. Getting a document by ID is much faster than querying for it. Querying means you are asking a question, whereas getting the object by ID means you already know the answer and are just telling the DB to go get it for you and is therefor faster.

If the ID is something that is random, then more than likely you must query the DB and that is less efficient. Couchbase Mobile's sync_gateway together with Couchbase Lite handles this on your behalf if you want it to as it can have its own keyspace and key pattern it manages for key lookups. If you are going straight to the DB on your own with the Couchbase SDK though, knowing that key will be the fastest way to get that object. Like I said, Couchbase Sync_Gateway handeles this lookup for you, as it is the app server. When you go direct with the SDKs you get more control and different design patterns emerge.

Many people in Couchbase Server create a key pattern that means something to their application. As an example for a user profile store I might consider breaking up the profile into three separate documents with a unique username (in this example hernandez94) for each document:

1) login-data::hernandez94 is the object that has the encrypted password since I need to query that all of the time and want it in Couchbase's managed cache for performance reasons.

2) sec-questions::hernandez94 is the object that has the user's 3 security questions and since I do not use that very often, do not care if it is in the managed cache

3) main::hernandez94 is the user's main document that has everything else that I might need to query often, but not nearly as often as other times.

This way I have tailored my keyspace naming to my application's access patterns and therefor get only the data I need and exactly when I need it for best performance. If I want, since these key names are standardized in my app, I could do a paralellized bulk get on all three of these document since my app can construct the name and it would be VERY fast. Again, I am not querying for the data, I have the keys, just go get them. I could normalize this keyspace naming further depending on the access patterns of my application. email-addresses::hernandez94, phones::hernandez94, appl-settings::hernandez94, etc.